# TestCafe tests failing in Chrome (works fine with Safari)

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm running the test on localhost, in Chrome, which clicks the button, navigates to a new page, and then navigates back to main page. My tests are failing when it goes back to main page with '404 this page could not be found'. Also noticed that each new url gets attached to the local host url. Such as : `http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xx:34327/SEcdCwbVu*Q2tjgyScm/http://localhost:3000/SEcdCwbVu*Q2tjgyScm/http://localhost:3000/SEcdCwbVu*Q2tjgyScm/http:/localhost:3000/main`

Not sure why it happens. With Safari tests are passing.

Browser: Chrome 104.0.5112.79 / Monterey 12

TestCafe version: 1.19.0

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following template to create a new GitHub issue and share the required information there: [Tempalte](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.yaml).

Regards,
Artemy